# How to properly play with the metronome when practicing Hanon exercises and scales on the piano?

Tags: piano, practice, metronomes

How to properly play with the metronome when practicing Hanon exercises and scales on the piano?

Should it be a note per beat? A bar per beat? How?

For example for Hanon, he states to set the metronome to 60 and gradually increase it to 108.

[image]

Comment: You'll notice that Hanon's metronome marking says a quarter note = 60 to 108.  One beat per quarter note is most usual practice, although Goku's answer is of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

It really does not matter, just do whatever keeps you in time. You could do one metronome beat per measure or do one metronome beat for each quarter note. It's really up to you.

Comment: yeah, that's what I try to do...for me usually, it makes sense to do a note per beat (when they are the same as in hanon exercises and scales). But I would like to know if there's a really proper way to do it and really understand it why...but thank you for your time and answer =)

Comment: @RiValé there is no set way to use a metronome, since when performing you won't be playing with one

Comment: It has to be a consistent way of doing it so it isn't subjective to the will of Hanon and mine xD, but I understand what you are saying and I agree with you.. I just really want to know the "scientific way" so to speak.

Comment: I'm almost completely sure that it's your decision how to use the metronome. I've played in a marching band and an orchestra and there was no strict determination of metronome usage, it's just used how the musicians need it.